# How do I calculate both onLoad and onChange with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get some calculation to function both when page loads and the selector changes, but can only get them to work separately.

As it is now the calculation only loads when the window loads not when the selector changes. And without `window.onload` the `onChange` works fine.

So my goal is for the calculation `portions * ingredient amount` in this case `p * 0.5` to load both when select `id="portioner"` changes and when pages loads.

```
            <ul>
            <strong><p class="litop" id="tightermobiletext">Hur många portioner? »</p></strong>
                <p class="litop"><select id="portioner" onChange="Calculate();">
          <option value=1>2 port</option>
          <option value=2>4 port</option>
          <option value=3>6 port</option>
          <option value=4>8 port</option>
          <option value=5>10 port</option>
          <option value=6>12 port</option>
                 </select></p>

            <li><label id="lblRes1"></label> Gul lök</li>
        </ul>




<script language="javascript">

    function Calculate() {
        var p = document.getElementById('portioner').value;
        var result1 = p * 0.5;document.getElementById('lblRes1').innerHTML = result1;
}

    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById('portioner').onchange = Calculate();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.onload = function() {
    //this line only sets the change property
    //do not put the () on the change
    //it needs to be a method reference
    document.getElementById('portioner').onchange = Calculate;
    Calculate(); //actually invoke the method on load
}
```

However, it is recommended to avoid the event properties and use the addEventListener now days.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    document.getElementById('portioner').addEventListener('change', Calculate);
    Calculate();
});
```

Comment: That worked great. Thank you so much to everyone who contributed!

Answer (score 1):

Additionally when you bind the function to the event handler you get `this` object. which you can use in the function like so

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
   let element = document.getElementById('portioner')
   element.addEventListener('change', Calculate);
   element.onchange();
});

function Calculate() {
    document.getElementById('lblRes1').innerHTML = this.value * 0.5;
}
```

a little cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Put the onload="Calculate()" bit onto the **body** tag as well as into the select tag identified as "portioner".

BTW it's the convention to start function identifiers with a lowercase letter.
So `calculate()` looks better than `Calculate()`